# Possible to get Furniture carpet beetle specimen for collection?

Tags: entomology

I was wondering if anyone knows how it'd be possible to get a *Anthrenus flavipes* (or furniture carpet beetle) specimen for my collection?

I can't find a source anywhere online, only the dermestid beetles used to clean skulls and such. Any help would be appreciated!

Bump

Answer (score 1):

You might try calling up a local exterminator (ideally not a franchise) and asking them to save you a specimen the next time they are called out to deal with such insects. Donate some beer/weed/customer referrals by way of thanks and they'll help you out with future specimen hunts.